# Airflow not writing logs to base log folder

Tags: logging, airflow

I have given remoteLogging as True in airfow.cfg. I have configured logstash to listen to the logs path. But since remoteLogging is true, logs are not written to base log folder. If that is false, logs are written. But, for me logs need to be written in local folder. I use airflow version 1.10.9 .What could I do for this?